# WSO2-APIM 2.1.0 to 2.2.0 upgrading issue: For the table IDN_OIDC_REQ_OBJECT_REFERENCE

Tags: java, sql, web-services, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using the [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release#1d09a673614e4b93807f1f92a541a215) for upgrading WSO2-APIM from 2.1.0 to 2.2.0 version.

While performing `step 6-g` I came across `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException` for creating a table `IDN_OIDC_REQ_OBJECT_REFERENC`.

My all other scripts ran successfully but at the time of executing sql scripts from `migration-resources\5.5.0\dbscripts\step1\identity\oracle.sql` the issue occurred. This file exist inside zip file given in `step 6-a`.

When I tried running following sql script manually

```
CREATE TABLE IDN_OIDC_REQ_OBJECT_REFERENCE (
  ID INTEGER,
  CONSUMER_KEY_ID INTEGER ,
  CODE_ID VARCHAR(255) ,
  TOKEN_ID VARCHAR(255) ,
  SESSION_DATA_KEY VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (CONSUMER_KEY_ID) REFERENCES IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (TOKEN_ID) REFERENCES IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN(TOKEN_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (CODE_ID) REFERENCES IDN_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_CODE(CODE_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

into oracle db I got following error:

```
Error at Command Line : 66 Column : 61
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view
```

Line `66` is nothing but: `FOREIGN KEY (TOKEN_ID) REFERENCES IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN(TOKEN_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,`

Let me know what thing  I've missed while doing the migration ? Or is it because of existing table are not proper ? Any help will be grateful. Thanks in advance.